# Why do my spacy tags not print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, spacy

So I have been trying to use spacy to tag text, and a few days ago in the same program I was able to do just that. However, when I tried to use it today I found that I would only get blankspace when I tried to output(not just print) any kind of tag outside of unicode. To make sure it had nothing to do with my program I opened up a new virtualenv, imported spacy again, and used the tagging documentation code without changing anything. Everything up to defining the 'doc' variable seems to work fine, and when I print out tags in unicode(without the underscore) it works just fine.

I am still unable to output any kind tag though. At this point I do not know what I need to do. What could be going wrong?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'They told us to duck.')
for word in doc:
    print(word.text, word.lemma, word.lemma_, word.tag, word.tag_, word.pos, word.pos_)
```

Comment: According to the documentation you also have to download the `en` model:
by using `python -m spacy download en`
https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models

Comment: Wow, did not see that at all, but it worked. Thanks!